# Copying 10 consecutively numbered files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file structure which looks like this:

```
Project
 |    
 +-- video_1
 |  |  
 |  +-- video_1_cropped
 |      |
 |      +--frame_00000.jpg
 |      +--frame_00001.jpg
 |      +...
 |      +—-frame_00359.jpg
 |    
 +-- video_2
 |  |  
 |  +-- video_2_cropped
 |      |
 |      +--frame_00000.jpg
 |      +--frame_00004.jpg
 |      +--frame_00005.jpg
 |      +…
 |      +—frame_00207.jpg
 |
```

Now these frames are not all numbered consecutively as they had been previously processed and not every frame was eligible to be processed. I would like to know if it is possible to go through all these directories, check if 10 frames are consecutively numbered and copy them to another directory, making a new directory there as well. The new directory would look like:

```
Videos
 |
 +-- video_00001
 |  |  
 |  +--frame_00000.jpg
 |  +--frame_00001.jpg
 |  +...
 |  +--frame_00009.jpg
 |
 +-- video_00002
 |  |  
 |  +--frame_00013.jpg
 |  +--frame_00014.jpg
 |  +...
 |  +--frame_00022.jpg
 ...
```

Some extra notes,

(1) I want to be able to copy multiple 10 frame sequences from the same video, if there exist multiple such sequences.

(2) If there is no 10 frame sequence in a video, then it can be skipped.

(3) If the sequence is longer than 10 frames, then I would want it to be split into 10 frame sequences still. So if the frames were numbered from 10-59, then I would create 5 new directories, each with 10 frames in them (frames 10-19, 20-29 etc.)

(4) The source videos shouldn’t be related to each other, as when the 10 frame sequences are copied to a new directory, they wouldn’t be in the same subdirectory anyways. So you should be able to copy the same sequence (e.x 20-29) multiple times from different videos.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show what you have tried so far, and what part of the problem you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

I just decided to write a Python script for this instead. Code if anyone is interested:

```
def process_pictures():
    video_directory = '/path/to/videos/'
    new_directory = '/path/to/sequences'
    new = 1

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(video_directory):
        if subdir[-7:] == 'cropped':
            curr = -1
            count = []
            for file in sorted(files):
                # get number
                number = int(file[-9:-4])
                # if the next file is consecutive
                if number == curr + 1:
                    # increment current and add file to list
                    curr += 1
                    count.append(file)
                    # if we found 10 files
                    if len(count) == 10:
                        # zero pad new folder to be made
                        video_num = f'{new:05d}'
                        new += 1
                        dir_name = new_directory + '/video_' + video_num
                        # try to make new directory
                        try:
                            # Create target Directory
                            os.mkdir(dir_name)
                            print("Directory " , dir_name ,  " Created ") 
                        except FileExistsError:
                            print("Directory " , dir_name ,  " already exists")
                        # loop through files and copy them to new directory
                        for f in count:
                            shutil.copy(os.path.join(subdir, f), dir_name)
                        
                        # create new empty list
                        count = []
                # if number is not consecutive, we reset the list and the current number
                else:
                    count = [file]
                    curr = number
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
typeset -Z5 destn=0
for dir in Project/video_<->/video_<->_cropped(Nn/); do
  files=() i=
  for file in $dir/*_<->.jpg(Nn.); do
    num=${(M)${file:r}%%<->}
    if [[ -z $i ]] || (( num == i + 1)); then
      files+=($file)
      if (( $#files == 10 )); then
        (( destn++ ))
        destdir=Videos/video_$destn
        mkdir -p $destdir && cp $files $destdir/
        files=() i=
        continue
      fi
    else
      files=($file)
    fi
    i=$num
  done
done
```